# akka.remote unit test does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, xunit

I am now telling the actor on another actor system to akka remote.

```
private void Handle(Start msg)
{
    var selector = Context.ActorSelection("akka.tcp://ConsoleApp2@127.0.0.1:9112/user/HelloActor");
    selector.Tell(new HelloActor.AAAAAAAAAA());
}
```

[Unit test]

```
var aaaa = ActorOfAsTestActorRef<HelloActor1>(HelloActor1.Props(), ActorPaths.HelloActor.Name);

aaaa.Tell(new HelloActor1.Start());

var msg = ExpectMsg<HelloActor.AAAAAAAAAA>();
```

The unit test says that the message was not received.

Why is that?